# Issue reading in a char array using sscanf in octal using either C or C++

Tags: c++, c, bit, octal

When trying to read in the octal value for "24" to an unsigned int, I get 0. Simply passing in the decimal value as a char array works.

I need the final value as a 32 bit unsigned int. The initial value is read in from a binary file.

## [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

simple.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char count[4] = "\030\000\000"; // Just "24" works
    __uint32_t value;
    sscanf(count, "%x", &value);
    fprintf(stderr, "%x", value);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and executed using

```
$ g++ simple.cpp -g
$ ./a.out
0
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Comment: you really need to be checking the returned value from system functions, like `sscanf()`,  If the posted code had checked the returned value, it would have been obvious that the call to `sscanf()` failed.   Any other problems in the code are secondary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The octal value `030` is a *single character* representing the special "CAN" (Cancel) control character in [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) (which is the most common encoding for the English alphabet and digits and punctuation).

When you use [`scanf` (or its sibling `sscanf`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) it will try to read digits, which in the ASCII encoding are the values `060` to `071` (for the digits `0` to `9`, inclusive).

To be able to use `sscanf` to read the number `24` you need to the two characters `'2'` and `'4'`. I.e. `"24"` (or `"\062\064"`).

---

If you want to convert the single character `'\030'` to the integer value `24`, then just do e.g.

```
value = count[0];
```

Comment: Some progammer dude, is there are way to force scanf to not look for the digits in ASCII encoding? I can't change the way the input is given.

Comment: value = count[0]; gives 18. Also it may be that the input is longer than one byte.

EDIT: It gives 24 when printed as a decimal. Nvm there.

Comment: @kshikama No, `scanf` (and its siblings) reads text-encoded strings.

Comment: @kshikama Octal 30 is decimal 24 is hexadecimal 18. If you want hexadecimal 24 you need decimal 36, octal 44 or character `'$'`.

Comment: I believe this doesn't work for input is longer than one byte? Can't think of a quick way to check my answer but. For example, the decimal value 24444 would be \057574. I'm not exactly sure how it is represented in C but...char count[4] = "\057574"; doesn't seem to be it.

But regardless, value = count[0]; would only capture the first byte I assume.

Comment: @kshikama You seem to misunderstand what a string is, and how it is represented. A string is a sequence of *characters*. The octal value `057574` is an *integer* value. If you want to represent an integer in a string you need to use the separate digit characters.

Comment: @kshikama You also seem to be misunderstanding how the parsing of strings into numbers work. If you have the string `"057574"` it can be converted into the integer `057574`, which is the same as the hexadecimal `0x5f7c` which is the same as the decimal value `24444`. If you try to parse the string `"057574"` as hexadecimal if will be the hexadecimal value `0x57574` which is the octal value `01272564` or the decimal value `357748`.

Comment: Well ok maybe I should rephrase the question. I have a buffer that looks like the following when printed in gdb: \000\000\000\200\000\000\000 . At some offset, there is the the decimal number 8192 hidden. 8192 is 20000 in octal. Thus I'm assuming the number is formed around that \200 somehow. Except \200 != 20000. 

Or another way to put it is, no matter how large the number I want to convert is do you believe the answer `value = count[0];` works?

Comment: I understand that "8192" parsed as decimal is 8192 and when parsed as octal it will be invalid and when parsed as hexadecimal it will be some value larger than 8192. Maybe I'm still not clear how strings are represented.

Comment: @kshikama What you seem to have is not a string, but an array of small integers. While they are very similar (in that they can both be represented as arrays of `char`), semantically they are very different. You need to treat it as an array of small integers instead of strings (using `uint8_t` or `int8_t` will make it more explicit).

Comment: Yeah but since I'm reading them into a char array (using fread), they are essentially a string, no?

Comment: @kshikama No no no. It's still an array of small integers. That you store it in an array of `char` doesn't matter. The embedded zeroes should be a clear indicator that this is not a string, and can not be treated as a string, because zeroes are the string terminator. You simply read some binary data into an array of bytes. The bytes are *not* characters. And please, if you want to read generic (signed) bytes into an array, make it an array of `int8_t` instead of `char`.

Comment: Hmm I see, so I guess I have to figure out how the small integers represent a larger one in this binary data. In case anyone is following this discussion is curious I'm reading in an ext2 file system image (as binary data). Anyways thanks for your help Some programmer dude, I think I got a direction now.

Comment: @kshikama If you want to understand how larger integers are stored using smaller, you need to know about [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and probably about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) (if you want to learn the most common way to handle negative numbers).

Answer (score 2):

I assumed that you get 4 bytes in a record coming from a binary file, and you want to convert those 4 bytes to an `uint32_t` value. I also assume that the bytes come with the expected endianness.

The simplest (and most standard conformant way) to do the conversion is to copy the byte representation to a variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char count[4] = "\030\000\000"; // Just "24" works
    __uint32_t value;
    memcpy(&value, count, sizeof(value));
    fprintf(stderr, "%d", value);
    return 0;
}
```

will return as expected `24`.

Comment: Ahh yes! Submitted some minor changes but this works indeed.

Answer (score 0):

here is a version of your code, that checks for an error on the call to `scanf()`

Note: that the unneeded C++ header files are commented out.

```
//#include <iostream>
//#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main( void )
{
    char count[4] = "\030\000\000"; // Just "24" works
    uint32_t value;
    if( 1 != sscanf(count, "%x", &value) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "sscanf failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, sscanf successful

    printf( "%x", value);
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the resulting output:

```
sscanf failed
```